# Way-cooler in NixOs

Tags: wayland, nixos

I've recently installed NixOs and I would like [way-cooler](https://github.com/way-cooler/way-cooler) to be my compositor. What configuration do I need to enable in the Nix config file?

Comment: I suggest you scroll down on the page you linked to and read it properly. You will find a link to the [NixOS package](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/window-managers/way-cooler/default.nix) ...

Comment: @DavidPostill yes I installed the package. However, when I try to run it directly I gives me errors about shared libraries. On Archlinux it runs flawlessly.

Comment: So what errors do you get? Telling us what actually happens might help someone tell you what you need to do.

Comment: And we are supposed to guess what those errors are? Please [edit] your question and explain properly what your issue is. And read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Seems enabling xserver in the Nix config installs all the missing libraries. I now get black screen with a mouse. Which is exactly what I didn't want to do as to have a lot of dependencies in the system.

Answer (score 0):

By looking [at the source code](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/b9851a975e8255f8799aed3f4efaa399e19ea733/nixos/modules/programs/way-cooler.nix) you will be able to enable it in your `configuration.nix` by adding something along the lines of `programs.way-cooler.enable = true`. It's jsut not in the stable release, yet.

Comment: You can also look in the manual: https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-programs.way-cooler.enable